# @url of ImageResource in external ClientBundle, to be used in UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Is it possible to reference an `ImageResource` with `@url` in UiBinder, when the `ImageResource` and the `UiBinder` **are not in the same package**?

For example:

My shared `ClientBundle` :

```
package com.myproject.client.resources;

class SharedResources extends ClientBundle {
    ImageResource myImage();
}
```

And, the UiBinder file in package com.myproject.client.**anotherpackage**

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <ui:with field="res" type="com.myproject.client.resources.SharedResources"/>
    <ui:style>
        @url myImg {insert reference to res.myImage}

        .theClass {
            background: myImg no-repeat center center #d7d6d6;
            width: 21px;
        }
    </ui:style>
    <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.theClass}"/>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

I know I could move the CSS to `com.myproject.client.resources` and then I would have easy access to the `myImage` (since the CSS and `myImage` would be in the same package), but I would prefer to keep the CSS **inside** the UiBinder and reuse the shared `myImage` from within the UiBinder.

There's a discussion regarding this issue here, but it does not answer my question:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/ExOJAEfQmkY

Comment: Two ways I can see doing this. First is [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Using_an_external_resource). Second is to simply create a CSSResource class and reference the ClientBundle in your UIBinder markup as shown in the link above. Is this on target for you?

Comment: I have tried `@url res.myImage`, but it does not compile. Is that the solution you were suggesting?

Comment: No. My suggestion was to pull your client bundle into the UI binder like in the example I linked. `<ui:with field='res' type='com.my.app.widgets.logoname.Resources'/>`. That would allow you to reference the `ImageResource` directly in the UIBinder. However, if you wanted to use a class, you could define a `CSSResource` which uses your image and use that class in your `HTMLPanel`.

Comment: Yep I get what you say, but I don't want to define another CSSResource. My goal is to keep the CSS class inside the UiBinder. I want to use an ImageResource that is inside an external ClientBundle.  Am I being clear enough? Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

I reached the same problem and my solution was to use `ui:image`. This solution will not reuse and refer directly to the ClientBundle like I think you want, but it gives you the possibility of not moving your CSS, or copying the image to your folder, or creating a new ClientBundle.

The code is something like:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <ui:with field="res" type="com.myproject.client.resources.SharedResources"/>
    <ui:image field="resImage" src="../resources/image.png" />
    <ui:style>
        @url myImg resImage

        .theClass {
            background: myImg no-repeat center center #d7d6d6;
            width: 21px;
        }
    </ui:style>
    <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.theClass}"/>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

I kept the `SharedResources` reference just to illustrate using your example, but it isn't being used in this case.